# Add context menu to VS 2010 solution explorer (display item on solution only)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-extensions

It is fairly easy to add a context menu item to the solution explorer in VS 2010. But how to display the menu item ONLY on solution items? Not on project items or something else?

Best regards,
D.R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_SOLNNODE"/>
```

and reset the experimental instance before restarting VSX (you can find the reset script in the VS start menu folder)

Comment: don't need to reset experimental instance, just "clean"+"build" your solution and changes will be applied