# VS 2013 (2015) extension on solution explorer context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

To add a context menu item to the solution explorer in Visual Studio, i can use the post [Add context menu to VS 2010 solution explorer (display item on solution only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418038/add-context-menu-to-vs-2010-solution-explorer-display-item-on-solution-only).

But is there a way to get the full filename of the selected solution? And how to get the context menu to show only on project files and solution files so i can do somthing with the project file?

Answer (score 0):

To get the full filename of the currently opened solution you can use `dte.Solution.FileName`.

To add a menu command to a project in Solution Explorer you probably want to specify `IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE` as the parent id.